# How to display an image only the first time an app is opened?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a very simple app and I would like to display a message the first time an app is opened. And not display after that at all.

The message will be on an image.

Is there any way to do this? I'm using swift code and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you know about NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a value that you can check against to see if your application has been launched once before. Put this in your `viewDidLoad` if you'd like to present your image when the application launches.

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if !defaults.boolForKey("haveRanOnce") {
        // First run of app
        // Present your message

        // Update defaults
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "haveRanOnce")
    }
```

[**NSUserDefaults Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but i am new to this: How do i get this code to display an image, as in, where do i add the code to bring the image up? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` which shows if the image has been shown. If it hasn't, show the image. It's probably easiest to add this logic into your root view controller when its view is shown, and then add the image as a subview or present a view controller to show the image. Alternatively, depending on what your app does, you could have a splash screen which shows loading progress (etc) and then have it check and show the image if required before proceeding to the 'true' root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can save `NSUserDefault` naming `NotFirstTime` to do this. When the application is launched for the first time there won't be any `FirstTimeLaunch` user default, therefore, it will return `false` as a default value. In this case you can display the image and set `NotFirstTime` to `true`.

On the second launch `NotFirstTime` will return `true` and in this case you should not display the image.

Here is the code to do so:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let name = defaults.boolForKey("NotFirstTime")
{
    /* don't display image here */
}
else
{
    /* display image here */
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "NotFirstTime");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a value of 1 in a variable. I the variable has a value of 0 then it is the first time the app has loaded. If it has a value 1 then it has been loaded before.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var isFirstTime = defaults.integerForKey("firstTime");

if isFirstTime == 0 {
    //Show image / message
    defaults.setInteger(value: 1, forKey "firstTime") //Set value to 1
}
```